# Plot two variables in bar plot side by side using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I think I need to use melt function but I'm not sure how to do so? Sample data, code, and resulting graph below. Basically, the "cnt" column is made up of the "registered" plus the "casual" for each row. I want to display the total "registered" vs the total 'casual" per month, instead of overall total "cnt"

[example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn2XP.jpg)

```
#Bar Chart
bar <- ggplot(data=subset(bikesharedailydata, !is.na(mnth)), aes(x=mnth, y=cnt)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title="My Bar Chart", subtitle = "Total Renters per Month", caption = "Caption", x = "Month", y = "Total Renters") +
  mychartattributes
```

[image]

Comment: I have made your second image public, but not your first one with the Excel-screenshot of the data. Try to extract the important part of the data without any additional columns, and use dput() to supply the data set.

Comment: Ooops, @r2evans published both....

Comment: Sorry, quick to edit ... and I agee that you should not post images of data.

Comment: @DieterMenne ok I did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "melt" your data use `reshape2::melt`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# Subset your data
d <- subset(bikesharedailydata, !is.na(mnth))
# Select columns that you will plot
d <- d[, c("mnth", "registered", "casual")]
# Melt according to month
d <- melt(d, "mnth")

# Set fill by variable (registered or casual)
ggplot(d, aes(mnth, value, fill = variable)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
    coord_flip() + 
    labs(title="My Bar Chart", subtitle = "Total Renters per Month", 
         caption = "Caption", 
         x = "Month", y = "Total Renters")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tidyr and dplyr:

```
set.seed(1000)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

bikesharedailydata <- data.frame(month = month.abb, registered = rpois(n = 12, lambda = 2), casual =rpois(12, lambda = 1))


bikesharedailydata %>% gather(key="type", value = "count", -month) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=month, y=count, fill = type))+geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]